# Sum Quantity from Opportunity Product Entity to a specific Field on an opportunity within the opportunity table

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have a list of opportunity product lines associated to opportunities that I want to pass to a field within the opportunity table so users can see this within the opportunity table view. The products in the opportunity lines are Number of learners. For projecting onboarding numbers for the month I want to add one field to my opportunity entity.

Total number of learners
This field would be populated by the total quantity of all "learners" products in the opportunity product lines.

I have tried a roll up field, but I can't seem to get it to sum up the quantity of products to appear within the new field created in the opportunity entity.

What features of Dynamics CRM could help me achieve this? MS workflow?

[Rollup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkGOH.jpg)

[Product Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4Id1.jpg)

[Rollup field on Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7LhY.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

[rollup field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/customize/define-rollup-fields?view=op-9-1#rollup-fields-benefits-and-capabilities) should solve your req.

If that does not solve your problem, Then you can create Power autome/ cloud flow.
If not you can create Plugin
If not Javascript.

But my best bet or choice would be rollup and then cloud flow.

Comment: Ank, thanks for responding. I've tried creating a rollup field but it doesn't bring back any result even though there are products within the opportunity. I'm I doing something stupid?

Comment: I've added screenshots to the original post.

Comment: Can anybody provide any help regarding this

Comment: could you add screenshot for your related records, maybe a view with column Line Item number.
In addition had you clicked on calculator next to your Leaner_Test field on form.